# Class Não Encontrada no Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tenho esse **Controller** no **Laravel 5**.

### HomeController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use View;
    use App\Portfolio;
    use App\Cliente;

    class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex(){

        # PORTFOLIO - Separado em Três Partes no Owl Carousel
        $portfolio['um']    = Portfolio::take(5)
                              ->whereStatus(1)
                              ->get();

        $portfolio['dois']  = Portfolio::skip(5)
                              ->whereStatus(1)
                              ->take(5)
                              ->get();

        $portfolio['tres']  = Portfolio::skip(10)
                              ->whereStatus(1)
                              ->take(5)
                              ->get();

        return view('frontend.home')
               ->withPortfolio($portfolio);
    }

}
```

Ele faz um **extends** do **Controller**.
E dentro desse **Controller** criei uma função.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController {

    use DispatchesCommands, ValidatesRequests;

    # Nome do Cliente no Portfolio
    static function NomeCliente($cliente){
        $explode    = explode(' ', $cliente);
        $varCliente = $explode[0].' <span>'.$explode[1].'</span>';

        return $varCliente;
    }

}
```

### View

`<h2>{!! Controller::NomeCliente($item->client->nome_fantasia) !!}</h2>`

Depois na **View** eu chamo essa função pelo **Controller**, como eu sempre fazia no **Laravel 4.2**.

Mas agora acontece esse erro:

> Class 'Controller' not found

O que está errado ou faltando ?

---

Eu criei um novo controller, chamado **NewController.php** apenas para teste.
Mesmo assim na **View** quando a chamo, também diz que não foi encontrada.

---

### Resolução

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Colocando o caminho completo do **Controller** na **View**. Ex:

`{!! App\Http\Controllers\URLController::Link('quem-somos') !!}`

Comment: o arquivo da Class ta com o nome igual da Class?

Comment: Sim. Resolvi a parada. Mas dentro do meu controller tem um **Request**, que não funciona. Dá o seguinte erro: **Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::segment() should not be called statically**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolução

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Colocando o caminho completo do Controller na View. Ex:

`{!! App\Http\Controllers\URLController::Link('quem-somos') !!}`